# get dict value from variable key in ansible

Tags: ansible

Here is my problem I need to get a dict value from key. But the key is also a var.
For example, I had an ansible role.

In **vars/main.yml**, I defined vars as below:

```
---
location:   "USA"
source:     {
             "China":  "/net/server1/patha",
             "USA":  "/net/server2/pathb",
             "Japan": "/net/server3/pathc"
            }
```

So in my tasks: **tasks/main.yml**. How do get "/net/server2/pathb" using the vars. I tried below in tasks, all did not work.

`-shell: "perl run.perl {{ source.location }}/script.pl"`

`-shell: "perl run.perl {{ source.{{ location }} }}/script.pl"`

This may be a simple question. But I searched many posts for a long time and still cannot get a right answer. So please help and many thanks.

Answer (score 39):

The answer is `{{ source[location] }}`.

Comment: It's indeed simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is a generic way of grabbing `vars/main.yml` that are just key-value pairs: `- name: echo_vars \
  command: echo "{{vars[item]}}" \
  with_items: "{{vars}}" \
  register: output_echo_vars \

- debug: var=output_echo_vars.stdout`

Comment: Accessing variables via `vars` is a tricky business – they are not processed trough templating engine in this case.