# How i can variable dict key in variable file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

in host file i have host vars:

```
XX.XX.XXX.XXX:
  role: value1
```

then in group vars there is:

```
my_dict:
  value1: [1,2,3]
  value2: [3,4,5]
```

in playbook i'm trying to reach the result_list:

```
- name: test
  hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: pong
    win_ping:  

  - debug:
      msg: "{{my_dict.value1}}"
# this message is ok

  - debug:
      msg: "{{my_dict.role}}"

#this fails
```

How can i get ther result value (list) threw the host variable role?

Answer (score 0):

my fail, bad searching: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631770/get-dict-value-from-variable-key-in-ansible)
and code will be:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{dds_hosts[role]}}"
```